# Why PhoneGap (cloud) packaged iOS app always shows default splashscreen image in iOS?

Tags: cordova, extjs, splash-screen, sencha-touch-2.3

I have created a cross platform app (to be packaged for iOS, Android and Windows Phone) in **Sencha Touch 2.3.1-gpl** and packaged it for iOS via **phonegap.com (Phonegap cloud)**. The app and the app icon work fine in all iOS devices but when the app is launched this default Phonegap **splash screen** is shown:

[image]

I can't find any option in the Phonegap (cloud) UI for selecting a splash screen for my app:

[image]

Now my questions are:

- Where or How can I define a custom splash screen for my app?
- Does the splash screen has to be specified in Sencha Touch app code? **OR** Does it have to be added somewhere in Phonegap (cloud) UI?

Here is my Sencha Touch app.js code in I haven't specified any icon or splash screen because as per my understanding icons and splash screens have to be added in Phonegap (cloud):

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({disableCaching: false});
Ext.application({
    name: 'RedmineApp',
    views: ['Issue', 'ProjectIssues', 'RedmineIssuesNavigator', 'RedmineTabPanel', 'RedmineChart', 'RedmineChartsNavigator', 'UserInputView', 'RedmineIDChart', 'RedminePriorityChart', 'RedmineTrackerChart', 'RedmineStatusChart', 'IssueHistory'],
    models: ['RedmineConfig', 'Issue', 'IssueCategory', 'IssuePriority', 'Project', 'ProjectMembership', 'Tracker', 'User', 'IssueStatus'],
    stores: ['RedmineConfigs', 'Projects', 'IssuePriorities', 'IssueStatuses'],
    controllers: ['Projects', 'Issues', 'ChartsMenu', 'UserInputFields'],
    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();
        // Initialize the main view
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('RedmineApp.view.RedmineTabPanel'));
    },
    projectIdentifier: null,
    redmine_url: '',
    redmine_access_key: '',
    loadRedmineConfig: function() {
        var configStore = Ext.getStore('RedmineConfigs');
        configStore.load();
        var redmine_config = configStore.getAt(0);
        if (redmine_config !== undefined) {
            this.redmine_url = redmine_config.get('redmine_url');
            this.redmine_access_key = redmine_config.get('redmine_access_key');
        } else {
            this.redmine_url = 'http://redmine.arkhitech.com';
        }
    },
    saveRedmineConfig: function() {
        var newRecord = new RedmineApp.model.RedmineConfig({
            redmine_url: this.redmine_url,
            redmine_access_key: this.redmine_access_key
        });
        var configStore = Ext.getStore('RedmineConfigs');
        configStore.load();
        configStore.removeAll();
        configStore.add(newRecord);
        configStore.sync();
    },
    setRedmineUrl: function(redmine_url) {
        this.redmine_url = redmine_url.replace(/\/$/, '');
        this.saveRedmineConfig();
    },
    getRedmineUrl: function() {
        if (this.redmine_url === '') {
            this.loadRedmineConfig();
        }
        return this.redmine_url;
    },
    redmine_base_path: '',
    setRedmineBasePath: function(redmine_base_path) {
        this.redmine_base_path = redmine_base_path;
    },
    getRedmineBasePath: function() {
        return this.redmine_base_path;
    },
    setRedmineAccessKey: function(redmine_access_key) {
        this.redmine_access_key = redmine_access_key;
        this.saveRedmineConfig();
    },
    getRedmineAccessKey: function() {
        if (this.redmine_access_key === '') {
            this.loadRedmineConfig();
        }
        return this.redmine_access_key;
    },
    setCurrentProjectIdentifier: function(projectIdentifier) {
        this.projectIdentifier = projectIdentifier;
    },
    getCurrentProjectIdentifier: function() {
        return this.projectIdentifier;
    },
    getCurrentProjectTrackers: function() {
        return this.projectTrackersStore;
    },
    setCurrentProjectTrackers: function(projectTrackersStore) {
        this.projectTrackersStore = projectTrackersStore;
    },
    getCurrentIssuesStore: function() {
        return this.createIssuesStore(this.getCurrentProjectIdentifier());
    },
    getCurrentProjectIssueCategories: function() {
        return this.issueCategoriesStore;
    },
    setCurrentProjectIssueCategories: function(issueCategoriesStore) {
        this.issueCategoriesStore = issueCategoriesStore;
    },
    loadProjectSettings: function(project_id) {
        var Project = Ext.ModelManager.getModel('RedmineApp.model.Project');
        Project.load(project_id, {
            success: function(project) {
                RedmineApp.app.setCurrentProjectTrackers(project.trackersStore);
                RedmineApp.app.setCurrentProjectIssueCategories(project.issueCategoriesStore);
            }
        });
    },
    createIssuesStore: function(projectIdentifier) {
        var newStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'RedmineApp.model.Issue',
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'dynamicrest',
                resourcePath: '/projects/' + projectIdentifier + '/issues',
                format: 'json',
                reader: {
                    rootProperty: 'issues',
                    type: 'json'
                }
            },
            grouper: {
                groupFn: function(record) {
                    return record.get('updated_on');
                },
                sortProperty: 'updated_on',
                    direction: 'DESC'
                }
            });
            return newStore;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by adding this **config.xml** file in the root of Sencha Touch App code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
            xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
            id          = "com.phonegap.example"
            versionCode = "10" 
            version     = "1.0.0" >

        <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

        <name>Your app name</name>

        <description>
            Your app description
        </description>

        <author href="http://www.author.com" email="info@email.com">
            Author Name 
        </author>
    <!-- iPhone and iPod touch -->
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />

    <!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

    <!-- iPad -->
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />

    <!-- Retina iPad -->
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />
    </widget>
```

After adding this file, Phonegap (Cloud) starts picking up the name, description and splash screen from this config.xml file instead of using its own defaults.